# How can I add text to a document footer using OpenXML?

Tags: openxml

I have a document template that I want to append some text to the footer. I've seen ways of deleting the footer to replace it, and ways to replace text in the footer, but I want to keep the footer as is from the template and just add to it. I have code to add text to the main doc., but unfortunately, main doc. parts are not setup the same way as footer parts. This is easily accomplished in Interop by a range.InsertAfter(text), but end users need this to work sans Word.

```
                FooterPart footer = _doc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
                string rid = _doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(footer);
                footer = _doc.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>(rid);
                Paragraph para = footer.AddPart(new Paragraph(), rid);
                Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get the last footer of the document
FooterPart footerPart = _doc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.LastOrDefault();
// create your paragraph. i created simple, but you will need to add style properties to the run or text class
Paragraph pr = new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("hello")));
// Insert the Paragraph to the end of the footer in footerPart.Footer
footerPart.Footer.AppendChild(pr);
```

Other way as you said would be putting a text to replace like "txttoreplace" and then you will find it and replace

```
IEnumerable<FooterPart> footerPartsList = Documento.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.ToList();
foreach (FooterPart hp in footerPartsList)
    foreach (Text text in hp.RootElement.Descendants<Text>())
    {
        if (text.Text.Contains("txttoreplace"))
        {
            text.Text = text.Text.Replace("txttoreplace", "new text");
        }
    }
```

And another way and the hardest would be, you insert the whole footer, with open xml productivity tools you get the c# code of the footer.xml, and then you delete the footer of the document and you insert.

Comment: I'm glad it's working! If you can vote for me in the answer above I would appreciate it.

Comment: Brilliant, seergius96 - you're a lifesaver!